# Express and realtime apps. Persist updates from client to server to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, express, mongoose

I am writing a realtime app. The basic principle is like a chat, but instead of text messages, users share youtube videos. The backend hasn't been completely done yet, and I don't know how I will do it. But I have some questions for what has been done.

Right now, user authentication with user/pass, FB, Twitter works well, and credentials are being stored in my db. User sign in works fine as well. Error messages get `flash`ed fine.

I'm using mongodb (mongoose) and express on the backend. It is not an API based design because I don't know how to work with user authentication in API's (I can make GET/POST/PUT/DELETE API, just don't know how to fit in authentication in there).

When a user, say, signin's using the homepage, the credentials are verified using `req.body.<field>` in an express.js route. If authenticated, redirect the user to a dashboard, else redirect to `signin` with flash messages. So, there are no Ajax calls, and right now, the app isn't realtime in any way. I'd like it to be realtime though.

So, leading to that, I have 3 questions:

---

1. I am using a modal window (bootstrap), to ask the user to update profile. The modal shows fine, except the field I want to be shown are not shown. The password and email fields are empty, even though I have a `value` attribute.

   ```
   input.form-control.dash(type="password", name="newuserpassword", ng-minlength=8, ng-model="password", value="__USE_EXISTING__")
   input.form-control.dash(type="email", name="newuseremail", required=true, ng-model="email", value=user.email)
   ```

   http://snappy-app.com/s/read.php?pass=9fc7ffa1e2b2140aad5232d5733f4caf
2. I want that when user edits the "Save" button, a message in the modal should either how any errors, or show that the update was successful. As it is, right now, my update method doesn't do this. Beyond redirecting the user, I don't know how can I achieve what I want.

   ```
   exports.update_user = function(req, res) {
       var user = new User({
           'username' : req.user.username,
           'password': req.body.newuserpassword || ,
           'email': req.body.newuseremail
       });

       console.log(user);

       user.save(function(err) {
           if (err) {
               console.log(err);
               for (var field in err.errors) {
                   var error = err.errors[field].message;
                   req.flash('error', error);
               }
               res.redirect('/dashboard');
           } else {
               req.logIn(user, function (err) {
                   if (!err) {
                       req.flash('success', 'Done!');
                   } else {
                       req.flash('error', 'Something went wrong.');
                   }
               });
           }
       });
   }
   ```
3. After the user updates the values by clicking "Save", the modal will close. The user can still click on the "Edit" link to change values yet again, and the modal will open. Now, based on what I have read, the user won't see the changes, because there hasn't been a page/modal reload. How do I make sure that the user sees updated values?

---

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: anyone has any inputs?

Answer (score 0):

When I read your text, I think:
"Hum, he tried to make an Ajax call and let the view display the errors or go on"

When I read your code, I think:
"Hum, it's a synchrone "give me all the page" call"

Which version do you want?

The Async one? So we can explain you the Ajax principle and your real problem is an UI update.
The Sync one? It's definitively an UI problem, and you should add a tag for it.

Comment: I'm starting with node/express stack, so I didn't know I was being vague. I'll edit the post to include some more detail. Also, why do you say the code is sync? The methods are used with callbacks.

Comment: I'm not speaking about the server internal stack but the full stack. Do you the view to make a post and refresh the entire webpage with errors if submit failed or another page if success? Or do you want the view to make an asynchronous call to the server, that responses with a json to the current view that will be modified?

Comment: Ideally the latter. That's what will help make my app real-time, and without page refreshes.

Comment: But if errors or sucess, your code render a full html page ... No?

Comment: Right now it does. But to get a more dynamic feel, I'd like this: User clicks on "edit profile", open a modal on top of current page, user changes password, if success, close modal, if not, without reloading the page, show error within the modal.